# Triple Integral for a Volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

I want to ask if my boundaries are correct. My steps and the exercise is one the Photo which I have uploaded.

$$ V= \left\{x\in \mathbb R^{3}|1/2<\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} <1; x>y; x,y>0\right\}  $$

$$   \Phi(r,\varphi, \vartheta)=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} r\cos(\varphi)\cos(\vartheta) \\r\sin(\varphi)\cos(\vartheta)  \\ r\sin(\vartheta)\end{pmatrix} $$

$$U=\left\{ (r,\varphi, \vartheta)| r>0; 0<\varphi<2\pi ; -\pi /2<\vartheta<\pi /2\right\} $$

For the Boundaries I have:

$$  -\pi /2<\vartheta<\pi /2 $$
$$1/2<r<1$$
$$\pi/4>\phi>0$$

Comment: which photo are you referring to?

Comment: I could not uploaded a Photo, thats why I Use Latex

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: Ok, thank very much.